# Date() - returns different values on different page

Tags: javascript, date

I have a very strange behavior in my web app. On one page, `new Date()` parsing works fine while on other pages, it seems like I get a totally different behavior from the `new Date()` parsing and it completely fails. I have verified that the Date object has not been overwritten extended or modified and I even tried using moment.js and I get the same results when it's converted to a `Date` object. I have also verified the same behavior in both Chrome and Edge. Any suggestions?

**Page 1** - Seems to work fine, when I type into console.

```
new Date()
```

> Mon Mar 25 2019 12:58:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

```
new Date("3/25/2019 12:29:51 PM")
```

> Mon Mar 25 2019 12:29:51 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

**Page 2** - For some reason parsing fails and returns a completely wrong `Date` value

```
new Date()
```

> Mon Mar 25 2019 12:58:52 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

```
new Date("3/25/2019 12:29:51 PM")
```

> Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

I also noticed that on page 1, `Date.parse("3/25/2019 12:29:51 PM")` works but when I try the same on page 2, it returns `null`.

Comment: `new Date("03/25/2019 12:29:51 PM")` -> "03" should work...

Comment: Still got my console up on Page 2, it didn't work.

new Date("03/25/2019 12:29:51 PM")
>>>>>
Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Comment: Could you provide working fiddle or something ?

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce the whole page in a fiddle, it's an asp.net app with various partials.... it must be something on my page. PS - updated my post to include info about Date.parse() returning null on page 2

Comment: Ahh!! i just saw that the problem page includes a script called https://github.com/datejs/Datejs , which probably IS modifying the Date object. I probably don't need it, I'll try removing it and seeing how things go.

Comment: FYI This doesn't seem to be a duplicate as RobG has marked. That has nothing to do with DateJS and an overwritten Date object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Page 2 was actually using a script called DateJS (so it was modified) that had some bugs in it too, when I updated the version to the latest, all issues were resolved. Thanks Rayon for your help.